# Rounded div clip-path in Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I wanna make something like this

[image]

I have made the shape with clip path and stacked component, what I have achieved is like this with this code

```
<div className="relative w-full lg:h-[220px] 2xl:h-80">
                  <div className="absolute w-full lg:h-[220px] 2xl:h-80 bg-[#2f3030] mt-10 p-3 [clip-path:polygon(0_0,65%_0,71%_18%,100%_18%,100%_100%,0_100%)]"></div>

                  <div className="absolute w-full right-0 top-0 bg-[#ff0000] lg:h-[220px] mt-10 2xl:h-80 [clip-path:polygon(67%_0,100%_0,100%_15%,72%_15%)]"></div>
                </div>
```

[image]

but the problem is, how can I make it rounded and add some gradient border like in the first image?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just couldn't solve it with only Tailwind. My alternative was to create a class named .clip-path (or any name) inside my globals.css and then apply that class to my div.